# Finding the number of functions that assigns an element from the codomain elements in the domain

Tags: functions, set-theory, computer-science

How do you find the number of functions that assigns an element from the codomain to elements in the domain? I will give a simple example to elaborate.

Given a set X = {0,1,2} and Y = {A,B}, and say we want to find the number of functions (X->Y) that assign A to 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 elements in the domain, each can be mapped to one of 2 elements in the co-domain.

There are 2 places the $0$ can go, 2 places that $1$ can go, and 2 places that $2$ can go.

There are $2^3$ functions.